# sbt: How to get dependent jar files list by Scala code

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm new to sbt. I'd like to know how to get dependent jar files by Scala code, not executing sbt plugin.

In Gradle, it supports to get dependent jar files by Java code like the following (`project` is an instance of [Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) class):

```
Configuration config = project.getRootProject().getBuildscript().getConfigurations().detachedConfiguration();
Set<File> jars = config.resolve();
```

I'd like to know a way to do like that in sbt and Scala. Does anyone know this? I tried to use `sbt.Project#dependencies`, but it seems that one doesn't meet for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `dependencyClasspathAsJars`:

```
sbt > inspect dependencyClasspathAsJars

[info] Task: scala.collection.Seq[sbt.internal.util.Attributed[java.io.File]]
[info] Description:
[info]  The classpath consisting of internal and external, managed and unmanaged dependencies, all as JARs.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  ProjectRef(uri("file:/home/claudio/foo"), "foo") / Compile / dependencyClasspathAsJars
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Classpaths.classpaths) Defaults.scala:1800
[info] Dependencies:
...
```

As you can see, this is a Task that returns a `scala.collection.Seq[sbt.internal.util.Attributed[java.io.File]]` where `Attributed` is just a simple wrapper around arbitrary data: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/api/sbt/internal/util/Attributed.html

```
sbt > show dependencyClasspathAsJars

[info] List(Attributed(/home/claudio/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.13.1.jar),                                  
  Attributed(/home/claudio/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/twirl-api_2.13/jars/twirl-api_2.13-1.5.0.jar),                                          
  Attributed(/home/claudio/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml_2.13/bundles/scala-xml_2.13-1.2.0.jar),                                  
  Attributed(/home/claudio/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-server_2.13/jars/play-server_2.13-2.8.1.jar),                                      
  Attributed(/home/claudio/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play_2.13/jars/play_2.13-2.8.1.jar),                                                    
  Attributed(/home/claudio/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/build-link/jars/build-link-2.8.1.jar),                                                  
  Attributed(/home/claudio/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-exceptions/jars/play-exceptions-2.8.1.jar),                                        
  Attributed(/home/claudio/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-streams_2.13/jars/play-streams_2.13-2.8.1.jar),                                    
  Attributed(/home/claudio/.ivy2/cache/org.reactivestreams/reactive-streams/jars/reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar),                                    
  Attributed(/home/claudio/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-stream_2.13/jars/akka-stream_2.13-2.6.3.jar),                                      
  Attributed(/home/claudio/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.13/jars/akka-actor_2.13-2.6.3.jar),                                        
  Attributed(/home/claudio/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/bundles/config-1.4.0.jar)
  ...)
```

If you want to process the value in any way, you probably want to write a custom task: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Tasks.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I could do that with `(dependencyClasspathAsJars in Compile).value` in my custom task.